# 3 sheeted cover of Klein bottle with torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

So I'm dealing with this exercise in which it is asked to determine whether the torus can be a 3-cover of the Klein bottle. A friend of mine came up with a proof that this is not the case, but this requires some long computations with fundamental groups. Does anybody of you know of a slick way to prove this using the theory of covering spaces?

Comment: I asked a similar question over 2 years ago http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619406/are-there-odd-sheeted-coverings-of-non-orientable-surfaces-by-orientable-surface . It is proved (in Ch.3 of Hatcher say), that every orientable covering of a non-orientable manifold factors through the orientation double cover. In particular a covering of a non-orientable manifold by an orientable must have even (or infinite) degree.

Comment: You can classify all 3-sheeted covers of the Klein bottle by looking at all transitive actions of its fundamental group on $3$ elements, and you can do this by exhausive search. So this is in principle a finite computation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why is it enough that we just look at the transitive actions for our purpose here? Could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: The transitive actions correspond to the connected covers and the torus is connected.